# Can't stiffen motors on Nao

Tags: nao-robot, choregraphe

I'm connected to my Nao via wireless. Two days ago, I had no problems running programs on my Nao, but today I'm having issues. I can boot up choregraphe and connect, but I can't stiffen the joints. I click the little sun icon a ton but nothing happens. I can get the Nao to say stuff, but not move since the joints won't stiffen. I tried a hard reboot on the Nao and on my laptop but it still doesn't work. Any ideas?

EDIT: When printing the error return from the wake up function, I got this:

```
[WARN ] ALMotion.LibALMotion :xCheckUnclampedSensorInsideLimits:0 In wakeUp, joint LShoulderPitch beyond the limit. AngleSensor (deg): 132.714 min (deg): -119.5 max (deg): 119.5

[ERROR] ALMotion.LibALMotion :wakeUp:0 WakeUp will not be performed because a wrong calibration has been detected.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else who has this problem: instead of just turning it on and off,  make sure you move it to a new position. I think that the shoulder joint was detecting a weird angle and therefore didn't know what to do. Put a print statement around the `wakeUp` function to better understand the error.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the first answer here (I cannot comment yet) - my V4 Nao was having these sorts of issues and readjusting randomly wasn't seeming to work.  Getting the full list of logs (Choregraphe 2.1.4, tick Show All Logs), it was saying LWristYaw was incorrect, and the wrist rotation was also showing incorrectly in the 3D viewer.  I am pretty sure this is because the sensor is malfunctioning.  I managed to get it to work by twisting it around and found a position that was within the ranges that are considered normal, and while he is permanently right-handed, he can now stand and do everything else he needs to do.  So, see if a specific joint is having issues, adjust and check, and be careful!

Comment: If I remember correctly (it's been many years since I've worked on a Nao), some of the joints cant rotate around more that 360 degrees and if this happens it can cause serious issues. That sounds like what may have been your problem? Not sure!